# Get the Style of a Control {StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}} in code behind

Tags: wpf, styles, default, code-behind

I want to grab the default `Style` for a `TextBlock` in code behind without ever having adding a custom default `TextBlock` `Style` to resources in `XAML`.

I've got a method like this:

```
public TextBlock DrawTextBlockAtPoint(string text, Style style)
{
    //...
}
```

that I want to provide an override that just uses the regular `TextBlock` `Style`:

```
public TextBlock DrawTextBlockAtPoint(string text)
{
   var style = GetDefaultStyleForProperty(TextBlock.StyleProperty);
   DrawTextBlockAtPoint(text, style)
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 9):

The [StaticResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) Markup Extension essentially tries to find a resource for the defines key. If the default style for the TextBlock type can be retrieved using: `{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}` you should be able to get it in code using:

```
var defaultTextBlockStyle = FindResource(typeof(TextBlock));
```

Of course, this needs to be called in a context in which the FindResource methods is defined. I used it inside my main Window class and it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped a lot: `typeof` and **using the container where the style was declared** (my case was a `StackPanel`, previously I used `FindResource `on the `Window` and it wasn't working).